# Google Analytics reporting timezone sessions not cut off at 24:00 (midnight)

Tags: google-analytics, reporting, timezone

When I'm viewing my GA stats at 00:34 I see this:
[image]

When I viewing them again at 10:00 I see this:
[image]

So there's a discrepancy between the numbers reported (141 users more when viewing later). I'd expect that at 24:00 all sessions would be cut off.
My reporting timezone is set to GMT+2 (in which I'm based myself as well if that matters)
[image]

So my question: **How can I make sure the stats reporting on a  daily basis with the cutoff point at 24:00 GMT+2?**

Comment: Hopefully this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37181666/how-long-google-analytics-take-to-process-the-data-from-the-day-before and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226066/google-analytics-update-frequency